# Merging ranked lists of disparate items

Tags: algorithm, merge

Let me start by saying that I don't think there is an analytically defensible answer to this question, but I'm open to being surprised.

The situation is that I have 11 ranked ordered lists of items, and I have been asked to combine them into a single rank-ordered list.  The issue is that these aren't 11 rankings of the same set of items (in which case I could use approaches like Schulze or Condorcet) but they are lists of totally different items.  So list one may be (A, C, D, B, F, E) while list two is (L, Q, M, G) etc.

With no common baseline, I don't see any way to say that just because something is number one on one list, it couldn't easily be less important than number N on another list.

Is there some wizardry out there that I'm ignorant of, or is this as intractable as I think it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there's not enough information to merge the lists meaningfully. The only thing that can be said is that some merges are wrong - those that contradict the original ones. That is very little.

Comment: I wonder if you found a sensible answer to this question or at least directions in textbooks or academic work

Answer (score 0):

You need more information to be able to have a definite answer.  For example, it could help to know if any of the lists more important than the other lists or if there are any common elements anywhere among the lists.

One thought might be to give each item a win/loss record and then rank according to winning percentage.  For your example, the results would be:

```
A 5-0 1.000
L 3-0 1.000
C 4-1 .800
Q 2-1 .667
D 3-2 .600
B 2-3 .400
M 1-2 .333
F 1-4 .200
G 0-3 .000
E 0-5 .000
```

You could end up with lots of ties and no way to break them.  This approach doesn't contradict the data and it does result in an overall ranking for the items, but there are also other ways to meet that criteria.  Without more information there really isn't any way to choose one over the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just *give* them a common baseline. You can treat them as if each of the 11 voters could have ranked all candidates (but just didn't do). Give all those who do not appear in one ranking a common, least-preference ranking. [The Schulze method can deal with that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method#Ballot).